# How do I boot from usb to install Ubuntu on Mac via Grub command line?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, usb, installation, grub

I tried all possible paths,

- set root (hd1)...' for all hdX
- chainloader +1
- boot

All i get is error: "cant find command line root"
I have no experience with grub, and I
just want to install ubuntu on an old macbook pro (overwrite whole thing)
please teach me (been hours)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to try to boot to the USB is to restart the computer and hold down the option key.

You should see a row of icons representing the bootable devices found, the USB would be an orange one with a USB logo on it, if it shows. Hopefully it does because then just highlight it and click the arrow underneath (or press enter).